# How to show Twitter Posting dialog Like Iphone

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am integrating twitter in my application and want to show twitter post dialog as available in iphone looks like the Image below.

[image]

Can we have this dialog in Android and how?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a bad idea to trying copy UI from a platform to another.

I recommand you to use the share intent:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

It's really easy to use and integrated with the platform.

Comment: Yes it ok But here i dont want to fire Intent to post on twitter. I am  using twitter4j sdk to integrate twitter in my app and want to post with it. I am just asking is twitter provide this dialog in android sdk too. This is just a web view.

Comment: I dont want to use Intent because for that user must have twitter in its device but what if user dont have twitter in its device

Comment: Okay it's a good reason :). I don't think this is provided by sdk. But I think it's easy to redirect your webview to the corresponding post page on Twitter mobile version.

Comment: I cannot test right now, but I think it might works with a simple webview and the Twitter web intent : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents

Comment: He's not trying to copy the UI, per se. He's trying to copy the UX. Indeed, getting the user out of your app and taking him to the browser so he can enter the credentials is BAD User Experience in my opinion. If you can create a Dialog like in iOS, and show inside your app, why not do it??
Take a loook on this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548117/twitter-login-dialog-error

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by finding twitter app from share intent if it is installed but if not you can handle that condition adn open your twitter app page as in my below code,since i found twitter4j hard to integrate and give inconsistence results.

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " text";

                    final PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
                    final List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);

                    boolean twtchk=false;

                    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {

                        if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
                            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                            System.out.println("package==="+activity.applicationInfo.packageName);
                            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                            v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
                            twtchk=true;
                            break;
                        }


                    }

                    if(!twtchk)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/yourapp"));

                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

Comment: Just what I was searching for. Is there a better way to target the Twitter PostActivity?