# signout using Twitter4J is not working with android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, android-twitter

I am using twitter 4j 3.0.2 jar 
I have integrate twitter in my android app.I have successfully login
and send tweet to twitter account but I face issue in logout from
twitter account from my android app.

I implement this as same as twitter4j sample app and I have noticed
that same issue also in twitter4j sample app.

Steps I have done

1. When first time I click on login button from my app then login page
   of twitter opened.
   2.I save token in SharedPreferences.
   3.Convert login button to logout.
   4.Now I clicked on logout button and clear token from shared
   preferences.
   5.Convert logout button to login
   6.Again Click on login then login page of twitter should be opened
   rather than authorize app page be opened.

My main issue is that how to signout from twitter from android app.Is
twitter cache is maintained in anywhere in device ? if yes then how I
clear twitter cache from my android app.

```
Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
        e.commit();
        //twitter.shutdown();
        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use force login in twitter.
For more details see my previous post

[Twitter Login Dialog error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548117/twitter-login-dialog-error/10548593#10548593)

So you just need to add **force_login=true** in your authorize url i.e

```
http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?force_login=true
```

Comment: - Vivek Kumar Srivastava i am using twitter4j.jar so, this will be inside my jar file i guess

Comment: I am also using twitter4j and this is not the part of jar file. If you don't know exact location then you can search by keyword "twitter.com/oauth/authorize" in your project

Comment: i have made a search inside my whole project its not avvailable

Comment: is your project having TwitterApp.java class?

Comment: No ,its not there inside my project

Comment: Okay...you can extract your jar file may may URL written in properties file. So you can change url on that file..other wise you need another code.

Comment: – Vivek Kumar Srivastava do you have any code available with you which you can share with me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30042/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-srivastava-and-hemant)

Comment: – Vivek Kumar Srivastava i am not able to tweet sir

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to clear the cookies.

Write the following one line code in your `onCreate` of the webview class.

```
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```

Hope it helps.

Above code will remove all your cookie(like twitter,facebook and any other)

To signout from twitter you need to set the twitter oauth cookie to null.

**`CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".twitter.com", "auth_token=''");`**

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue just changing Call back url from oauth://t4jsample to... public static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?force_login=true";