# Android-How to logout from twitter4j library?

Tags: android

Already tried appending `force_login=true` to callback URL and clearing the shared preferences. Even after doing the above it shows the authorize app page and not the login page.

Answer (score 0):

"You need to use force login in twitter. For more details see my previous post" see: [signout using Twitter4J is not working with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581232/signout-using-twitter4j-is-not-working-with-android)